# Execute immediate 'alter table' error pl/sql

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have a table and I want to create a copy of it. But I want this copy to be dynamic. First table may change. In a FOR LOOP, for each i (except 1), I want to alter the second table and add a column with the name "Col"+"i". Example: Col1, Col2, Col3.
While debugging, everything is ok except this line: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||tab_name||' ADD Col'||i||' NUMBER(2)';` which throws 2 errors: "ORA-01403: no data found" and "ORA-06512"
What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

```
CREATE TABLE first_table (
id NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
col1 NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
col2 NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
col3 NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
col4 NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
col5 NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
col6 NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
col7 NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE second_table (
first_col NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE second_table
AS
nr_columns NUMBER(2);
tab_name VARCHAR2(20);
col_nam VARCHAR2(20) := 'COL';
BEGIN

SELECT COUNT (*)
INTO nr_columns
FROM user_tab_columns 
WHERE table_name='FIRST_TABLE';

SELECT table_name
INTO tab_name
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE column_name ='FIRST_COL';

FOR i IN 1..NR_COLUMNS
LOOP

IF (i=1) THEN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||tab_name||' RENAME COLUMN FIRST_COL TO id';
ELSE
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||tab_name||' ADD Col'||i||' NUMBER(2)';

END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works perfectly for me.

**Tables**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE first_table (
  2  id NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  3  col1 NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
  4  col2 NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
  5  col3 NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
  6  col4 NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
  7  col5 NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
  8  col6 NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
  9  col7 NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL
 10  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE second_table (
  2  first_col NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
  3  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

**Procedure**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_second_table
  2  AS
  3    nr_columns NUMBER(2);
  4    tab_name   VARCHAR2(20);
  5    col_nam    VARCHAR2(20) := 'COL';
  6  BEGIN
  7    SELECT COUNT (*)
  8    INTO nr_columns
  9    FROM user_tab_columns
 10    WHERE table_name='FIRST_TABLE';
 11
 12    SELECT table_name
 13    INTO tab_name
 14    FROM user_tab_columns
 15    WHERE column_name ='FIRST_COL';
 16
 17    FOR i IN 1..NR_COLUMNS
 18    LOOP
 19      IF (i=1) THEN
 20        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||tab_name||' RENAME COLUMN FIRST_COL TO id';
 21        dbms_output.put_line('if');
 22      ELSE
 23        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||tab_name||' ADD Col'||i||' NUMBER(2)';
 24        dbms_output.put_line('else');
 25      END IF;
 26    END LOOP;
 27  END;
 28  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> sho err
No errors.
SQL>
```

I have added **DBMS_OUTPUT** to show you when it goes into **IF-ELSE** block.

Let's **test** it and see:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> EXEC p_second_table;
if
else
else
else
else
else
else
else

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Let's check **table definition**:

```
SQL> desc second_table;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ---------
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER
 COL2                                               NUMBER(2)
 COL3                                               NUMBER(2)
 COL4                                               NUMBER(2)
 COL5                                               NUMBER(2)
 COL6                                               NUMBER(2)
 COL7                                               NUMBER(2)
 COL8                                               NUMBER(2)

SQL>
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Line 11 is like this: WHERE table_name='FIRST_TABLE'; and it returns 8 columns.

Comment: Provide create statement for first_table.

Comment: Thanks it works for me now! I dropped the table and tried doing it again. It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this query

```
SELECT table_name
INTO tab_name
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE column_name ='FIRST_COL';
```

Error

> ORA-01403: no data found

means that select didn't return a single row. Check if table `second_table` exists, or may be you have created it in another schema and now works in another. Also check name of column `SECOND_TABLE.FIRST_COL` in `user_tab_columns`

Comment: I made a mistake while posting the code, but I updated it now. But anyway, there's still the same error.